# Ruby split binary string where the previous character is different from the next one

Tags: ruby

I wonder how could I split a binary string in Ruby.
I want to split the string where the previous character is different from the next one.

for example if i have the string

```
    @s = "aaaabbabbaa"
```

I would like to create an array of strings

```
    @array[0] = "aaaa"
    @array[1] = "bb"
    @array[2] = "a"
    @array[3] = "bb"
    @array[4] = "aa"
```

How could i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression with `scan`:

```
@array = @s.scan(/((.)\2*)/).map(&:first)
#=> ["aaaa", "bb", "a", "bb", "aa"]
```

Answer (score 3):

[Enumerable#chunk](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) does that, but its defined on Enumerable - and String does not include Enumerable. Transform it into an Array of chars (and glue them back to strings) , like:

```
s = "aaaabbabbaa"
p array = s.chars.chunk(&:itself).map{|a| a.last.join} #=>["aaaa", "bb", "a", "bb", "aa"]
```

Comment: You are getting an extra letter for each item in the array, maybe adding `.map(&:pop)` before `.map(&:join)` helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "aaaabbabbaa"

r = /
    (?<=(.))  # match any character in capture group 1, in positive lookbehind
    (?!\1)    # do not match capture group 1, negative lookahead
    /x        # free-spacing regex definition mode

str.split(r)
  #=> ["aaaa", "a", "bb", "b", "a", "a", "bb", "b", "aa", "a"]
```

By using two lookarounds no characters are lost when splitting on the regular expression.

Comment: Wasn't aware of `/x`, nice.

Comment: @Gerry, `/x` is, imo, the best way to document non-trivial regexes, but note that it disregards spaces. For example, `/a b/x` reduces to `/ab/`. You'd have to write `/a[ ]b/` or `/a\sb/` to preserve the space.

Answer (score 1):

using [Enumerable#chunk_while](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while)

```
str = "aaaabbabbaa"
p str.chars.chunk_while(&:==).map(&:join)
```

Output : `["aaaa", "bb", "a", "bb", "aa"]`

Comment: Why use `chunk_while`, which requires Ruby v2.3+, when `chunk` is simpler, reads better and supports earlier versions of Ruby?

Comment: `chunk_while` seems more intuitive to me, as in more generic than chunk, i used to use it while coding

Comment: I don't think `to_a` is necessary here.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 yeah thanks, just noticed as it returns enumerable so we can go for method chaining directly

Comment: You can use the shortcut `chunk_while(&:==)`